# Error: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram, but I'm keep getting this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
plt.hist(a)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2827, in hist
stacked=stacked, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8312, in hist
xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 21, in _amin
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I'm very new to python and what I'm trying to do is this;

```
import numpy, matplotlib.pyplot

line = " "
a = []
b = []
c = []
alpha = []
beta = []
gama = []

while x.readline():
    line = x.readline()
    a.append(line[16:23])
    b.append(line[25:32])
    c.append(line[27:34])
    alpha.append(line[40:47])
    beta.append(line[49:54])
    gama.append(line[56:63])

pyplot.hist(a)'
```

when ever I run this piece of code I'm getting that error. Where did I go wrong? I really appreciate a help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to draw the histogram based on strings, rather than on numbers. Try something like this instead:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import random
# generate a series of numbers
a = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in xrange(100)]
# generate a series of strings that look like numbers
b = [str(n) for n in a]

# try to create histograms of the data
pyplot.hist(a) # it produces a histogram (approximately flat, as expected)

pyplot.hist(b) # produces the error as you reported.
```

In general it is better to use a pre-written library to read data from external files (see e.g., [numpy's `genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)).
But at the very least, you likely need to treat the data you have read in as numerical, since readline returns strings.  For instance:

```
for line in f.read():
    fields = line.strip().split()
    nums = [int(field) for field in fields]
```

now `nums` gives you a list of integers from that row.